# HYPERBOLA : Problem

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

If two points $P$ and $Q$ on the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} -\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$
whose centre is  $C(0,0)$ are such that $CP$ is perpendicular to $CQ$ , $a<b$ , then prove that
 $$\frac{1}{(CP)^2} +\frac{1}{(CQ)^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} -\frac{1}{b^2} $$

Comment: It should be $1/(CP)^2\color{red}{+}1/(CQ)^2=1/a^2-1/b^2$.

Comment: @mathlove that's right . Ive made the changes

Comment: I have a doubt regarding this . Cant i assume (asecθ,atanθ)(asec⁡θ,atan⁡θ) and (−asecθ,−atanθ)(−asec⁡θ,−atan⁡θ) as the two points of tangency ? (because the points of tangency are symmetrically located)

If i am wrong , Please provide a explanation why so ?

Thanks !